# Python says a variable is undefined even though it's clearly defined

Tags: python

I was making a game in Pygame, and I was making a variable that was used in the update function, but it says it's undefined. I've looked it up so much, but couldn't find anybody having the same problem:

```
# Code Vars
SIN_COUNTER = 0

# Code
def update():
    SIN_COUNTER += 8
    SIN_COUNTER = math.sin(SIN_COUNTER)
```

EDIT: I've used other variables that I've declared earlier in the script and they worked.

EDIT #2: The error is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'SIN_COUNTER' referenced before assignment

EDIT #3: Please don't get mad at me. I'm new to Pygame and just Python in general.

Comment: What is saying that it's undefined? Your development environment? A specific python error printed to the console? A NameError that you caught?

Comment: The error is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'SIN_COUNTER' referenced before assignment

Comment: Note: you can read a global variable w/o declaring global, but can’t change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the interpreter is not wrong. There is indeed no *local* variable named `SIN_COUNTER`, only a global one. You have to explicitly declare within the function's context that the symbol `SIN_COUNTER` refers to a global object:

```
SIN_COUNTER = 0

def update():
    global SIN_COUNTER
    SIN_COUNTER += 8
    SIN_COUNTER = math.sin(SIN_COUNTER)
```